# Calculate modulo with polynoms

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I have a question where I can't get my head around. I don't know where to begin with the calculus.
Let:
$p = x^2 + b$ 
$q = x^3 + a$
$t = x^5 + a*x^3 + b*x^2 + b$

Calculate $ p*q \pmod t $

I had experience with modular exponentiation, but with the form
$ a^b \pmod m $. The problem is, I have here multiples b and quite frankly lost on how to proceed. Or is it the wrong approach? Thanks for helping me in advance!

Comment: But is $t$ a polynomial? Or a number?

Comment: [Maybe useful](http://eiche.theoinf.tu-ilmenau.de/fingerprint/ueber_polynome_modulo-englisch.pdf)

Comment: I think t must be a polynomial. I'll check the document out, thanks;